# PostgreSQL update time zone offset

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone, timestamp

What's a quick and easy way to correct the time zone `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` fields accidentally entered in the wrong time zone?

In my case, the following records were mistakenly input in UTC rather than in US/Pacific:

```
           t0           |           t1           |     what
------------------------+------------------------+---------------
 2011-06-01 13:00:00+00 | 2011-06-01 13:10:00+00 | recalibrating
 2011-06-01 13:10:00+00 | 2011-06-01 13:45:00+00 | verifying
 2011-06-01 13:45:00+00 | 2011-06-01 13:55:00+00 | FAULT
```

Fortunately, none of the mistaken records cross daylight savings boundaries, so 2 o'clock UTC can simply be corrected as 2 o'clock Pacific.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE <table>
SET <timestamptz_field> = 
  (<timestamptz_field> AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') AT TIME ZONE '<correct_time_zone>';
```

Answer (score 6):

There are casts and, more importantly, the `at time zone` operator, which are useful for this kind of thing, e.g.:

```
test=#  select now(),
               now()::timestamp;

              now              |            now             
-------------------------------+----------------------------
 2011-06-27 14:32:04.169292+02 | 2011-06-27 14:32:04.169292
(1 row)

test=# select now() at time zone 'utc',
             (now() at time zone 'utc')::timestamp with time zone;

          timezone          |           timezone            
----------------------------+-------------------------------
 2011-06-27 12:32:28.430479 | 2011-06-27 12:32:28.430479+02
(1 row)
```