# Save datetime value from Django to Postgres

Tags: django, python-3.x, postgresql

This is my `views.py`:

```
class UpdateListMyShipmentView(UpdateView):
    model = models.Shipment
    fields = []

    def get_success_url(self):
        return reverse_lazy('request:my_shipment')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(timezone.localtime(timezone.now()))
        form.instance.time_finished_shipment = timezone.localtime(timezone.now())
        form.save()
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

This is the value of print() method in command line:

```
2018-06-15 16:54:29.499707+07:00
```

And this is the result in database after saved value into database:

```
2018-06-15 09:43:39.025761+00
```

Why it is different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database timezone and project timezone are different. That explains the +00 vs +07:00 difference... but the difference in minutes ( 43.36 vs 54.29 ) i guess it is just a copying error?

Comment: Can you talk more detail or give me a keyword to solve issue above, pls?

Comment: @QuocHuy if you wish you can fix the problem on django side by setting the timezone value to the same that database has: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/i18n/timezones/#default-time-zone-and-current-time-zone. Do that if database is running UTC timezone (if project is global) or when database uses your local timezone (if project is local). Otherwise do the change in postgres. In any case: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12675723/changing-time-zone-value-of-data